# Why MouseMove is not fired on a custom FrameworkElement?

Tags: c#, wpf, custom-controls

I cannot get fired the MouseMove event on a custom FrameworkElement, which will be used as a host for Drawings.

The case is shown in the next example code:

```
namespace WpfAppTest
{
  public class VisualPresenter : FrameworkElement
  {
    private readonly List<Visual> VisualChildren = new List<Visual>();
    public Size ViewSize = new Size(500, 300);

    public VisualPresenter()
    {
        var DrwVis = new DrawingVisual();
        using (var Context = DrwVis.RenderOpen())
            Context.DrawDrawing(
                  new GeometryDrawing(Brushes.LightSkyBlue, null,
                                      new RectangleGeometry(new Rect(ViewSize))));
        this.VisualChildren.Add(DrwVis);
    }

    protected override int VisualChildrenCount { get { return VisualChildren.Count; } }

    protected override Visual GetVisualChild(int index)
    {
        if (index < 0 || index >= VisualChildren.Count) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        return VisualChildren[index];
    }

    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size AvailableSize)
    { return this.ViewSize; }

    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size FinalSize)
    { return base.ArrangeOverride(FinalSize); }

    protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        // Why this is not fired when the mouse is over???
        Application.Current.MainWindow.Title = "Moving at: " + e.GetPosition(null);
    }
  }
}
```

This "custom control" (if that concept aplies here) can be easily tested when inserted in the main window xaml...

```
<Window x:Class="WpfAppTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfAppTest"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="700" Width="600">
    <Grid>
        <local:VisualPresenter />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

So, what is missing?

UPDATE 1:
I've discovered that the mousemove event is triggered when mouse is captured, such as when adding the next line in the VisualPresenter constructor:

```
this.Loaded += (s, e) => CaptureMouse();
```

UPDATE 2:
Alternatively, the mousemove event also is triggered when, instead of using a List a VisualCollection is used to register the children. But I would prefer to use the List to store more than just the visual (i.e. a key to identify those exposed visuals).

Comment: If it doesn't have background = no mouse events. Add some (`Transparent` color will do).

Comment: Well, it has to be `Control` to have background, as a bonus you will get `ControlTemplate`.

Comment: You can subscribe to mouse events of `Parent` of your `VisualPresenter`. Parent should have background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After analyzing (source code deep dive) how the VisualCollection class works, I discovered that the missing part is to **attach the new visual object to the underlying WPF visual tree**. So, now we have...

```
this.VisualChildren.Add(DrwVis);  // This only shows the visual
this.AddVisualChild(DrwVis);      // This links the visual to its parent
```

and voila! The hit-testing Works and the mousemove event is fired.

Comment: What is DrwVis?

Comment: DrwVis is a variable of type DrawingVisual

Answer (score 1):

None background considered as hollow and not able to absorb mouse events. Framework Elements does not have a visual by default. So hit test will be done based on what drawn in OnRender method. Hit test can be enabled by drawing an empty Transparent rectangle on render.

```
    protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
    {
        drawingContext.DrawRectangle(Brushes.Transparent, new Pen(Brushes.Transparent, 1), new Rect(0, 0, this.ActualWidth, this.ActualHeight));
        base.OnRender(drawingContext);
    }
```

Comment: A Control has too much features (such as templating) aside from just show Drawings, so is not an option.